# Source model "Meigee_CategoriesEnhanced/category_attribute_source_block_menutype" not found for attribute "meigee_cat_menutype" in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Source model "Meigee_CategoriesEnhanced/category_attribute_source_block_menutype" not found for attribute "meigee_cat_menutype"

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete all references to the meigee theme you probably are removing.

Use the following statements in the database:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code LIKE "%meigee%";

DELETE FROM eav_attribute_group WHERE attribute_group_name LIKE "%meigee%";
```